# Changing style bits in eclipse rcp css

Tags: java, css, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a question about changing the style of SWT controls via css in eclipse rcp applications.

When I activate css spy I can see that my control has some style bits set in the css rules window on the bottom right (e.g. `SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT`). This was determined upon the Control's costruction.

Can this style bit be changed via css? A concrete example will be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Style bits can't be controlled from CSS. SWT style bits can only be specified when the control is created and CSS is not used at that point.

You can use the style bits in CSS selectors to control which CSS is used.